# C# static class - calculate the size

Tags: .net-4.0, static, size

Suppose I have a C# static class. It contains only only static methods. How do I calcute the size of it? What does affect  its size in the memory?

And how much would it weigh if I included static fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll never be creating any instances of it, so the size is pretty much irrelevant.

Obviously as you add more methods they will take *some* memory (the IL, the JIT-compiled native code etc) but no more so than anywhere else - and almost certainly not significantly within your app.

If you add some static fields, again those take up memory - but they're only associated with the type, rather than any instances of the type. So if you add (say) a static field of type `long`, that will take an extra 8 bytes per `AppDomain` you load the type into. Insignificant in the grand scheme of things.